# List available audio inputs and open the selected as a stream

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, audio-recording

I want to write an application in windows forms .Net 4 c# to list the available input devices and then when the user press a button it opens the input device as a stream.

I have no idea how to do this and google doesn't seem give me any hits on doing this!

sorry if this is very easy but I can't seem to get a foot hold on this!

there after i want to analyse the data from the stream but I can't find how to do the "easy" bit.

thanks for any help..

Comment: .NET has no support for this at all.  You'll need to find a library that supports this, check out NAudio: http://naudio.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hi Thanks NAudio likes promising, But can find no way of marking this an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started: [WinMM Library Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710650/winmm-library-issues)

Comment: Thank you, but NAudio seems more complete.